# SQL: how to SELECT by value if value can be null

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, android-room, isnull

I have a database table "Category" which can have a self-reference. If self-reference is null, then it's a top-level category (no parent). If it's pointing to another category, it's a subcategory of the given category.

Now I'm trying to setup query which returns all subcategories with given parent category id. Something like following (Android Room syntax):

```
"SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = :parentId"
```

This query returns nothing if parentId == null, but I would like it to return all categories where parentId == null (i.e. top-level categories). With a query

```
"SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id IS NULL"
```

I can get parent categories successfully, but obviously, it's not working for subcategories.

I tried also the following query

```
"SELECT * FROM category WHERE (parent_id IS NULL OR parent_id = :parentId)
```

but it fails of course, since it always returns top-level categories, even though the intention is to get only certain set of subcategories.

My question is, how I can set up my query so that it works as expected, i.e. returns all top-level categories when parentId == null, otherwise it returns all subcategories of given category id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL standard requires this handling of NULL values.

But SQLite has an extension: you can use IS also with non-NULL values:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id IS :parentId
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a slightly more complicated condition:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM category c
WHERE (c.parent_id IS NULL AND :parentId IS NULL) OR
      (parent_id = :parentId);
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't make it work. Answer from CL. worked.